# Moving origin/master to HEAD instead of merging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-merge

I have a git repository for which `git log --graph --all` gives me this a the top of the tree:

```
* 726523b - (HEAD, master) Clean-up in .gitignore (2013-05-23 15:46:51 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
* 5585a01 - Removed build-dependent elements (2013-05-23 15:13:16 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
| * 6d53b1c - (origin/master) Language fix (2013-05-22 22:08:26 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
|/  
* 3e6650e - Minor changes to readme and license, after moving back to github (2013-05-22 21:29:44 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
```

Now, I want to get the commit `6d53bc` into `master`, but to get the history as I want I'd prefer to cherry-pick that commit into the master branch (to avoid a merge commit and complicated branch history, when the work is really linear). But when I do that, `origin/master` still stays where it is, and I can't push any changes in `master` since the branches have diverged.

Is there a way to merge or cherry-pick `6d53b1c` into `master` that will make the history look as if the commit was just one of the others on the same track? Essentially, this is what I want to end up with (ordering of commits is unimportant, as long as `master` and `origin/master` are in the same place):

```
* 726523b - (HEAD, master, origin/master) Clean-up in .gitignore (2013-05-23 15:46:51 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
* 5585a01 - Removed build-dependent elements (2013-05-23 15:13:16 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
* 6d53b1c - Language fix (2013-05-22 22:08:26 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
* 3e6650e - Minor changes to readme and license, after moving back to github (2013-05-22 21:29:44 +0200) <Tomas Lycken>
```

Comment: Is the order important? If not, `git pull --rebase` will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of cherry-picking, it would be better to [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) your local `master` work on top of `origin/master`, like this (when on the local `master` branch):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This will give you the linear history you want, and then you can push to `origin/master`.

You can read more about [`rebase` at the official Git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be the best option. I had a couple of other branches as well, and rebasing each one of them did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Running `git rebase origin/master` or `git rebase @{u}` from your master branch should do the trick.  Be careful though.  Rebase skips merge commits (introduced by you on master) by default, and using `git rebase -p` (don't skip merge commits) is not generally what you want either.

You can fetch and rebase in one step with `git pull --rebase`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

will just replay `6d53b1c` (so you get a new commit, new hash, same effect) on top of `origin/master`.

You have a linear history with no merge, but the "Language fix" will come *after* `726523b`.